# rename the specific file with current time stamp using perl script for windows

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using the below script to rename but it is renaming the all file end with STA.I need to rename the file that starts with KRAT or TRAT.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use File::Copy; 

my $directory = 'C:\Users\Desktop'; 

chdir($directory) or die "Can't chdir to $directory $!"; 
opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Couldn't opendir: $!\n"; 

my @files = grep { $_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..' } readdir DIR; 

foreach(@files) { 
    print $_,"\n"; 
    my $newName = $_; 

    $newName =~ s/STA$/t00/g; 
    print "RENAMING: $_ -> $newName \n"; 

    rename($_, $newName); 

}
```

Comment: I used below code  

#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;


my $directory = 'C:\Users\rajkunal_aps\Desktop';

chdir($directory) or die "Can't chdir to $directory $!"; 
opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Couldn't opendir: $!\n";  

my @files = grep { $_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..' } readdir DIR; 

foreach(@files)
{   
print $_,"\n";
my $newName = $_;   
$newName =~ s/STA$/t00/g;   
print "RENAMING: $_ -> $newName \n";   
rename($_, $newName); 
}

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: It looks like you've picked up someone else's script and posted it here to get it modified to your requirement. That isn't how programming works. You should at least make some effort of your own before getting the rest of the world to do your job for you.

Answer (score -1):

Change the line

```
$newName =~ s/STA$/t00/g;
```

to

```
$newName =~ s/^KRAT|^TRAT/t00/;
```

or more succint.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory = '<DIR>';

chdir($directory) or die "Can't chdir to $directory $!";
opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "Couldn't opendir: $!\n";

rename_file($_) for grep { $_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..' && /^KRAT|^TRAT/} readdir DIR

closedir(DIR);

sub rename_file {
    my $name = shift;
    $name =~ s/^KRAT|^TRAT/t00/;
    rename($_, $name);
}
```

Comment: No ,It is not working----
I have file -ABC.txt,CDE.STA.LMP.STA,GYI.STA
and i need to update only GYI.STA to GYI.txt

Comment: why rename only `GYI.STA`? why not `CDE.STA` etc?

Comment: @AruneshSingh You can write the regex as `^(?:KRAT|TRAT)`

Comment: I have requirment for particulat type file only.not all

Comment: This will replace `KRAT` and `TRAT` with `t00` instead of `STA` with `t00`

Comment: `map` is meant to implement a *mapping* from one list to another, and it is wrong to use it in void context. You need a simple `for` here, like this `rename_file($_) for grep { $_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..' && /^KRAT|^TRAT/} readdir DIR`

Comment: `use File::Copy` is superfluous.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to use `map` in void context. That expression is better written as `rename_file($_) for grep { ... } readdir DIR`.